# A new entity was found through the relationship

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, embed

The error message:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Tarifa#pesos' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   AppBundle\Entity\TarifaPeso@0000000072d3bd4300000000232470d3. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AppBundle\Entity\TarifaPeso#__toString()' to get a clue.

Tarifa.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TarifaPeso", mappedBy="tarifa")
 */
private $pesos;
```

TarifaPeso.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tarifa", inversedBy="pesos", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tarifa_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $tarifa;
```

TarifaType.php

```
        ->add('pesos', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => TarifaPesoType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false
        ))
```

The controller...

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $tarifa = new Tarifa();

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\TarifaType', $tarifa);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($tarifa);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'project.created_successfully');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_post_index');
    }

    return $this->render('admin/tarifas/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

What am I missing? Really exhausted... please any help?

Comment: Are you handling the form submit yourself?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the controller code, I've updated it. I changed 'em->persist' with 'merge' and it works but it does not store the embed class (TarifaPeso)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should move `cascade={"persist"}` annotation from `TarifaPeso::tarifa` to `Tarifa::pesos` property. Or you can explicitly persist all `pesos` you get from the form:

```
$entityManager->persist($tarifa); 
foreach ($tarifa->getPesos() as $peso) {
     $entityManager->persist($peso);
}
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: great! it save data in TarifaPeso table but not the tarifa_id in the TarifaPeso table (the foreign key it is not saved, only the other two fields), do I have to add anything else? tnaks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it is solved, now it stores the Tarifa id in the TarifaPeso table. The error was I'd removed the line from the AddPeso method:

```
public function addPeso(\AppBundle\Entity\TarifaPeso $pesos)
{
    $this->pesos[] = $pesos;
    $pesos->setTarifa($this);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Which one is "the line"?